# break values in pandas column into bins

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following DataFrame:

| columns1 | parametr_1 | parametr_2 | parametr_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val_1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| val_2 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| val_3 | 7 | 1 | 7 |
| val_4 | 4 | 2 | 11 |

I want to break each column into bin, so it would look something like this:

| column | bin | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| parametr_1 | (0-1) | 2 |
| parametr_1 | (1-inf) | 2 |
| parametr_2 | (0-2) | 3 |
| parametr_2 | (2-inf) | 0 |
| parametr_3 | (0-5) | 2 |
| parametr_3 | (5-inf) | 2 |

and maybe having each parametr cell merged so I would only have single parametr_1, parametr_2 and parametr_3 cells in second column

Maybe there is a specific library to that?

Comment: What is logic for defined bins?

Comment: `pd.cut` can provide the bins. Using dict comprehension it is possible to retain the column names while itterating over the DataFrame. The follwing snippet produces almost full results, but requires a `count`: `pd.concat({col:pd.cut(vals,3,) for col,vals in df.iloc[:,1:].items()})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is specified bins for each `parameter` column by dictioanry and call [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), then count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), remove rows with missing values, convert to integers:

```
d = {'parametr_1':1,'parametr_2':2,'parametr_3':5}

for k, v in d.items():
    df[k] = pd.cut(df[k], bins=[0, v, np.inf])

df = (df.set_index('columns1')
       .apply(pd.value_counts)
       .melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='count', var_name='column')
       .dropna(subset=['count'])
       .astype({'count':int})
       .rename_axis('bin')
       .reset_index()[['column','bin','count']])
print (df)
       column         bin  count
0  parametr_1  (0.0, 1.0]      2
1  parametr_1  (1.0, inf]      2
2  parametr_2  (0.0, 2.0]      4
3  parametr_2  (2.0, inf]      0
4  parametr_3  (0.0, 5.0]      2
5  parametr_3  (5.0, inf]      2
```